# How does MySQL transaction works and When to rollback?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, pdo, transactions

i wonder how does transaction work. 
**Question is do I need to rollback if any error/exception occurs**, where the Exception will be thrown and never reach the *commit()* call? If so why and how? and what rollback does exactly?

consider the followings PHP code (some Java code does similar things like so):

```
public function deleteAll():void{
    $stmt = $this->con->prepare(
            'DELETE FROM dd WHERE 1'
        );

    $this->con->begin_transaction();
    if(!$stmt->execute()){
        throw new Exception($stmt->error);
    }
    $this->con->commit();
}

public function insert(array $list):void{
    $stmt = $this->con->prepare(
        'INSERT INTO dd(cc) VALUES(?)'
    );
    $stmt->bind_param('s', $v);

        $this->con->begin_transaction();
    foreach($list as $v){
        if(!$stmt->execute()){
            throw new Exception($stmt->error);
        }
    }
    $this->con->commit();
}
```

Note: 
*$this->con is the mysqli connection object (not using PDO, although different but PDO and mysqli will do similar thing like above).
database is MySQL, table using InnoDB engine.*

Some people code shows they catch the Exception and do rollback. But I did not since the *commit()* is never executed if Exception is thrown. Then this let me wonder why does it need to rollback at all.

My assumption is if there are multiple queries to perform at once like the following:

```
public function replaceAllWith(array $list):void{
    $this->con->begin_transaction();
    try{
        //do both previous queries at once
        $this->deleteAll();
        $this->insert($list);

        $this->con->commit();
    }catch(Exception $e){
        //error
        $this->con->rollback();
    }
}
```

but then it still cannot rollback because each method/function is done and committed by different method and different transaction. 
**Second Question: Do I do each transaction in each method call, or only invoke transaction in the *'boss/parent'* function which only call and coordinate *'subordinate/helper'* functions to do work?**

Not sure if I'm asking the right questions. 
Database Transaction is confusing, many online resources show only the procedural process (commit only or then immediately rollback which make no differences to normal direct query) without OO concepts involved. Please any pros guide and give some advice. tq.

Comment: You should only be Committing/Rolling back in one place. Normally that would be in the Controlling code and NOT in the functions called from the controlling code

Comment: You should also only be beginning a transaction from the controlling code as well.